# Wordpress wpdb undefined variable

Tags: wordpress

I'm writing a plugin and trying to request some data from a custom table in my database using:

```
$current_text = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT text FROM addtext ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");
```

but just get the error Undefined variable: wpdb

Any idea why this isn't working? I've followed the docs and scoured Google, with no luck. Still pretty new to WP plugins so probably something obvious.

Thanks!

Answer (score 56, accepted):

I needed to use `global $wpdb;` in my function.

Comment: 2.5 years later, and your answer helped me. Thanks!

Comment: 3 years later, and your answer also helped me. Thanks!

Comment: 4 years later, and your answer did it again! Thanks!

Comment: 5 years later, and your answer did it again! Thanks!

Comment: 6.7 years later.

Comment: 7 years later, and your answer did it again! Thanks!

Comment: 9 years later, and your answer did it again! Thanks!

Comment: 10 years later, and your answer did it again! Thanks!

Comment: 11 years later. The gift that keeps on giving.

Answer (score 7):

One note to add: You cannot use `global` inside a class, and of course you have to use `global` in order to get your objects to work using `$wpdb`.

While you can't use `global` *immediately* inside a class, you must declare `$wpdb` as `global` *inside a function* inside the class, and this does work.

e.g. This gives you an error:

```
class wpdb_test {
        global $wpdb; // can't use global as a direct 'child' of a class
        public function __construct () {
            ...
        }
}
```

Because `global` can't be used directly inside a class. Likewise, simply referencing `$wpdb` inside the class *also* gives you an error because the object doesn't know what `$wpdb` is. You have to declare `$wpdb` as `global` from inside a function that is inside your class.

e.g. This works just fine:

```
class wpdb_test {
        public $variable_name;
        public function __construct () {
            global $wpdb; // safe to use because it's inside a function
            ...
        }
}
```

...and because `$wpdb` has been declared `global` inside a function *inside* a class you are able to use it.

Comment: Thanks @RalphTheWonderLlama, you just saved a php newbie some frustration.